# Where should I post a self-answered question about my experiences with hungarian notation?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I'm thinking of writing up a fairly detailed account of naming patterns I found helpful and pitfalls I ran into while developing a semi-greenfield database app. Specifically, using Apps hungarian notation for everything in the database and front end.

Does this fit better on Programmers or SO? SO has more questions like this, but a fair number are closed.

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without knowing what you're about to write. What question title do you have in mind? Beware that on most sites questions about naming conventions are closed as "Draws opinionated answers".

Comment: Hmm. Something about "Apps hungarian naming patterns that have proven helpful in database projects", maybe.

Comment: It does sound a bit more like a blog post rather than a Q&A post to me based on your brief precis

Comment: This primarily sounds like it wouldn't be a good fit for any SE site; naming conventions are somewhat opinion-based by default, and the whole topic sounds rather broad given it involves all of the app from database to front end. Seems like it could make a good blog post, but not a good, specific, factual q/a pair. It definitely doesn't belong on SO, and I'd doubt it would fit programmers.

Comment: @l4mpi: As far as too opinion-based, I don't think that will turn out to be a problem in practice. The only real question is whether it's too broad, I guess. I might just have to write up a fuller draft and see if it works.

Comment: SOunds like a blog post to me, too

Comment: since you mention Programmers, consider taking a look at related meta guidance: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6583/31260)

Comment: write it on your blog, SE is not suitable for such "articles"